# How to get all values in a string enum?

Tags: typescript

I have a string enum and need to get all the values. For instance, for the below enum, I'd like to return `["Red", "Yellow"]`:

```
export enum FruitColors {
    Apple = "Red",
    Banana = "Yellow",
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Just tried this, and it worked perfectly! It wasn't showing up in my `lib.d.ts`, but became available after setting `"target": "ES2017"` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Noting that this only works for String enums - which is what the question asked - but it doesn't work for "normal" enums.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the `FruitColors` object.

Note that if you do ***not*** assign names for the enum values, the generated code will be different and a simple key/value based mapping will lead to wrong results. e.g.

```
export enum FruitColors {
    "Red",
    "Yellow",
}

Object.values(FruitColors); // ["Red", "Yellow", 0, 1]
```

Because the generated code is along these lines:

```
var FruitColors;
(function (FruitColors) {
    FruitColors[FruitColors["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
    FruitColors[FruitColors["Yellow"] = 1] = "Yellow";
})(FruitColors = exports.FruitColors || (exports.FruitColors = {}));
```

You could then just filter the results by `typeof value == "string"`.

Comment: This answer is not relevant because it's not using a string enum. Values are int as clearly visible in the output.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17198#issuecomment-315400819), this can be achieved the following way:

```
Object.keys(FruitColors).map(c => FruitColors[c]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this function, it can return all values in string + number enum type, not only string Enum

```js
const getAllValuesEnum = (enumType: any) => {
  const keysAndValues = Object.values(enumType);
  const values = [];

      keysAndValues.forEach((keyOrValue: any) => {
        if (isNaN(Number(keyOrValue))) {
          values.push(enumType[keyOrValue] || keyOrValue);
        }
      });

      return values;
    };
```

Example:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  A = "a",
  B = 7,
  C = "c",
  D = 1,
}
```

It will return [ 1, 7, 'a', 'c' ]